# Text area Jmeter Question

Tags: java, jsp, webforms

I tried to use JMeter to send HTTP request. One of the input field is a textarea. each line in this text area need to be passed in. How do I specify a new line of input in text area? I tried %0 , space, coma... but it din't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to encode a newline character using '%0A'.  This encoding would be equivalent to a '\n' (LF) character.  If you want to simulate a Windows style newline '\r\n' (CR+LF), you would use '%0D%0A'.  If you specify the encoding directly into the parameter text field value, then you will not want to check the 'Encode?' option for that parameter as you manually included the encoding.

If this does not work, please include the values you are using in your JMeter script and the result you are seeing on your server.  Also include how you are monitoring the server values.

I would also make sure to add a 'View Results Tree' Listener to your script so that you can see the actual Request/Response data that was sent by your script.  It is useful to make sure that the values you are sending are what you expect.

Comment: OMG IT WORKS. THANK YOU SO MUCH. I have tried to search for this in the last 2 hours.